# mod_slotmem_shm is causing error in apache2.4.29 loading

Tags: module, solaris, apache2.4

I am in process of upgrading from apache 2.2 to 2.4.29, while everything is working fine without ssl and ssl. But when I try to use proxy modules along with slotmem_shm modules, which is according to my understanding is mandatory now while using load balancers modules, I am getting following errors in error_log :

```
[Fri Mar 16 17:52:12.073931 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 15571:tid 1] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Mar 16 17:52:12.275257 2018] [slotmem_shm:error] [pid 15571:tid 1] (17)File exists: AH02611: create: apr_shm_create(/usr/local/apache_QA_New/logs/slotmem-shm-p9cbf72c_check.shm) failed
[Fri Mar 16 17:52:12.275543 2018] [proxy_balancer:emerg] [pid 15571:tid 1] (17)File exists: AH01185: worker slotmem_create failed
[Fri Mar 16 17:52:12.275721 2018] [:emerg] [pid 15571:tid 1] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
```

I have been brainstorming for last 2 weeks. I have tried different solutions  like increasing kernel semaphores memory, they were about 128K which I have increased to 16384K, but this solution still does not seem to work and it does not seem to be proper solution either.

There are almost 30 balancers entries in my balancer file and more than 50 virtual hosts entries in httpd-vhosts.conf and at each restart apache creates some file for shm and then go down and it keeps doing so until creation of all files for which I have to restart it again and again.

Comment: *I have tried different solutions like increasing kernel semaphores memory, they were about 128K which I have increased to 16384K* That has nothing to do with shared memory file creation.  The code that is failing can be found here:  https://github.com/apache/apr/blob/trunk/shmem/unix/shm.c#L144  Without knowing how your version of Apache was compiled, it's almost impossible to know which code path is taken in the source I've linked to.

Comment: here is my config enable-mods-shared=all"
enable-ssl"
enable-modules=all"
enable-autoindex"
enable-setenvif"
enable-alias"
enable-so"
enable-cache=shared"
enable-status"
enable-rewrite"
enable-proxy"
enable-proxy-connect"
enable-proxy-ftp"
enable-proxy-http"
enable-proxy-balancer"
enable-mem-cache=shared"
enable-file-cache=shared"
enable-headers=shared"
enable-usertrack=shared"
enable-expires=shared"
enable-deflate"
enable-proxy-ajp"
enable-nonportable-atomics=yes"
disable-charset-lite"
with-mpm=worker"
with-ssl-lib=/usr/sfw/lib"
with-ssl=/usr/sfw"
with-included-apr"

Comment: Note : apr and apr-util is placed in srclib of apache

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I am dealing with something similar installing apache on RHEL 8 (httpd-2.4.37) with a config with many balancers/vhosts.

Comment: yes , I resolved the issue by using "--enable-posix-shm" while running the config.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with underlying SHM stuff and everything to do with how multiple balancers, global and outside of virtualhosts, are initialized and sometimes persisted.  This was changed greatly in 2.4.29.

You should find the minimal set of balancers that reproduces the error and open a bug at issues.apache.org.  It is likely related to duplicate virtual hosts or duplicate proxy "workers".